# Where should the user-independent configuration for a multi-app system exist within the registry?

Tags: unity-game-engine, registry

I apologise if this seems like a question with no clear-cut answer (although I'm hoping there is one), but please bear with me...

The company I work for is developing an immersive environment in Unity, which consists of a box-shaped room with multiple projectors casting images onto the walls and ceiling to produce a sort of effect similar to VR, but without the need for a headset. We're using Unity and C# to develop the system, and I've been writing a sort of "platform" that acts as a starting point for the applications that we develop for the environment. One of the systems contained within this platform is for screen configuration; this includes the dimensions of the screens and the mapping of projectors to views (i.e. it indicates which projector is responsible for projecting the forwards view .etc.)

Now, in order to make things simple, I'm going to be storing this configuration within the registry; this way, all of the separate applications will share the configuration of the immersive environment. I've implemented this, and everything works as expected. However, as I'm pedantic about things, I just want to make sure I'm using the correct location within the register for what I'm storing.

At the moment, I'm using "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\BlueRoom..." ("Blue Room" is the name of the environment we're developing). I know I'll want to store the configuration within HKLM as opposed to HKCU, as the setup of the Blue Room's screens are the same regardless of the user. However, beyond this I'm not sure if I should be storing the configuration in "\System\BlueRoom..." or "\Software\BlueRoom...". Are there set guidelines pertaining to this, or is it a matter of preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in the "\Software\BlueRoom\" seeing as that's what it is. System is more reserved for things that pertain to the functionality of the system e.g. Hardware and Windows.